# Basic HTML Link Send PHP Variable

Tags: php

This is my first go at trying to create a secure login feature.

Right now I have a `mysql database` storing a few usernames and passwords.
I also have a `bootstrap` template for a login page.

Here is some of the `html`:

```
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-label-group">
          <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="required" autofocus="autofocus">
          <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-label-group">
          <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="required">
          <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="connect.php" method="post">Login</a>
    </form>
```

I added the method and changed the action for the login button/link.
I would like to be able to click the login link and have the input values sent to an external `php` program `connect.php` shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<div>
    <?php
    $user = $_POST["inputEmail"];
    $pass =  $_POST["inputPassword"];
    echo "<h1>Hello: ".$user."   also:".$pass"</h1>";
    ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Once I can get the values to send to the external script, I can then start to check the values against those in my database.

Solutions I have seen are mostly dealing with the `form action` and not a link. Those that are dealing with a link use `get` and hard code the values being sent rather than `input`.

**EDIT 1:**

I realized my html page was launching outside of my server. I made some changes to my `html`:

```
    <form method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-label-group">
          <input type="email" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="required" autofocus="autofocus">
          <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-label-group">
          <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="required">
          <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="connect.php" method="post" name="submit">Login</a>
    </form>
```

after these changes its telling me my inputs are `Unidentified index`'s

Comment: Your form needs a `method='post'` on it. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data under the `method` attribute

Comment: @aynber I had that initially but the values were not making it over

Comment: Your inputs also need a `name` attribute

Comment: And you also need an `action="connect.php"` and a submit button

Comment: @aynber shouldnt `id` work?

Comment: @AlonEitan the question is about using the link which is my button to send the data

Comment: Nope. `id` does not get sent with the form. Only `name` and `value`

Comment: So I don't understand how the link is related to what you wrote: _"This is my first go at trying to create a **secure login feature**."_ what do you think makes a login form secured?

Comment: not sure, its my first go at it but my understanding is storing encrypted credentials in a database. I wouldn't think it would matter how the values are being sent to the script that checks against the db @AlonEitan

Comment: @FamousAv8er Do _NOT_ store _encrypted_ credentials. Store _hashed_ credentials. (PHP has functions `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`)

Comment: @aynber please see edit 1

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton noted, thank you

Comment: @FamousAv8er you can remove `method="POST"` from your submit link. Why does it need to be an `<a>` tag? Try adding `type="submit"` to your submit link.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton thats the way the bootstrap template had it. I wanted to keep the styling so I left it as is. I will make those changes though, thanks

Comment: @FamousAv8er Weird. I've used bootstrap before, never saw that markup. I suggest changing it to a `<button>` element, you can keep the rest exactly the same just have to change the element tag.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton i thought so as well. Its the `SB Admin` template.

Comment: I'd move the action from the a link to the form tag, and it would make more sense to have the submit as a button or input instead of an `a href`, so that it's an input and not sending a GET request.

Comment: @FamousAv8er Actually looking at the code, using a link there wouldn't work. It wouldn't submit the form, it would just redirect to the ending page.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**
change submit link to submit button & make sure to run on a server

```
    <form action="connect.php" method="POST">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-label-group">
          <input type="email" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="required" autofocus="autofocus">
          <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-label-group">
          <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="required">
          <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="submit" type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
```